# Python - Search for hex value marker and extract data

Tags: python, parsing, binary, hex

I am new to python and have tried searching for help prior to posting.

I have binary file that contains a number of values I need to parse.  Each value has a hex header of two bytes and a third byte that gives a size of the data in that record to parse.  The following is an example:

```
\x76\x12\x0A\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
```

The `\x76\x12` is the record marker and `\x0A` is the number of bytes to be read next.

This data always has the two byte marker and a third byte size.  However the data to be parsed is variable and the record marker increments as follows: `\x76\x12` and `\x77\x12` and so on until `\x79\x12` where is starts again.

This is just example data for the use of this posting.

Many Thanks for any help or pointers.

Comment: Are the hex values always separated by a backslash?

Comment: Is this the real string content or its Python representation?

Answer (score 1):

Is something like this what you want?

```
>>> b = b'\x76\x12\x0A\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> io = StringIO(b)
>>> io.seek(0)
>>> io.read(2) #read 2 bytes, maybe validate?
'v\x12'
>>> import struct
>>> nbytes = struct.unpack('B',io.read(1))
>>> print nbytes
(10,)
>>> data = io.read(nbytes[0])
>>> data
'\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Comment: Personally, I'd've just used `nbytes = ord(io.read(1))` rather than bothering to use the `struct` module here.

Answer (score 0):

This will treat the data as a raw string (to ignore '\' escape character and split into a list

```
a = r"\x76\x12\x0A\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00".split('\\')
print a
```

output: ['', 'x76', 'x12', 'x0A', 'x08', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00']

You can then iterate through the values you are interested in and convert them to decimal if required:

```
for i in range(len(a[4:])): # cutting off records before index 4 here
    print int(str(a[i+4][1:]),16)
```