# Python: search binary file for n-byte hex value

Tags: python, search, binary

I have a binary data set that I would like to search for a hex value. My code needs to be able to handle little and big endian data (the byte order is pre-determined). A sample of my byte array (little endian) is below. `'ba'` is a byte array with my data

```
>> print repr(ba[:10])
bytearray(b'\x01U\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf4\xf1\x0f&')
```

EX: I need to search for `0x5501` which in this case are the first two bytes, `0x01` and `0x55` (because `'U' == 0x55`)

In looking at this related question ([Python - Search for hex value marker and extract data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17297230/python-search-for-hex-value-marker-and-extract-data)), they are using the StringIO module. What is the fastest / best way to do this while allowing for little or big-endian data.

The data is in a byte array from a previous byte-wise decryption process

Comment: The struct module allows for different byte orders, it might help.

Comment: "Data" doesn't have endianness, only representations of values do.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams so, when documentation says something like "The value 0x12345678 is stored to allow the decoder to determine byte storage order", That is referring to the machine the arbitrary decoder is running on? Or the machine that created the file?

Comment: The machine that created the file. The machine that is decoding the file must see which bytes are actually used to represent that value so that it can determine what endianness the values in the file have.